# Mudar de lugar os quadrantes de uma matriz de tamanho par

Tags: c, array, matriz

Eu recebo uma matriz, e devo imprimi-la na tela como mostrado na imagem a baixo.

---

[image: Como deve ser a saída]

---

Esse é o código atual:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int matriz[4][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    int l, c;


    for(l = 0; l < 4; l++){
        for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){
            printf("%2.i ", matriz[l][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(l = 0; l < 4; l++){
        for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){
            if(l >= 0 && c <= 1){
                printf("%i ", matriz[l+2][c+2]);    
            }else if(l >= 0 && c >=2){
                printf("%i ", matriz[l+2][c-2]);    
            }else if(l >= 2 && c <= 1){
                printf("%i ", matriz[l-2][c+2]);    
            }else if(l >= 2 && c >= 2){
                printf("%i ", matriz[l-2][c-2]);    
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


return 0;   
}
```

---

E esse o resultado que obtive, por algum motivo esta pegando o lixo da memoria, e não os valores da matriz na hora de imprimir a parte inferior, a parte superior esta correta, mas a inferior não estou conseguindo, alguém sabe como resolver e me dar uma luz ? agradeço muito.

> [image: Resultado que obtive com o código atual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas validações suas estavam erradas, se você validar `l>=0` vai permitir que qualquer `l` entre nessa condição, isso aconteceu nos dois primeiros `ifs`, a validação correta é `l<2`, veja abaixo:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int matriz[4][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};
int l, c;


for(l = 0; l < 4; l++){
    for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        printf("%2.i ", matriz[l][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n");

for(l = 0; l < 4; l++){
    for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        if(l < 2 && c <= 1){
            printf("%i ", matriz[l+2][c+2]);    
        }else if(l < 2 && c >=2){
            printf("%i ", matriz[l+2][c-2]);    
        }else if(l >= 2 && c <= 1){
            printf("%i ", matriz[l-2][c+2]);    
        }else if(l >= 2 && c >= 2){
            printf("%i ", matriz[l-2][c-2]);    
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poxa mano, valeu, era isso mesmo, erro tao bobo de falta de atenção que me custou 5 meses kkkkkk, estou dês de novembro do ano passado tentando resolver esse problema, so que com uma imagem, muito obrigado